# Karate aggregate karate-summary.html when there are multiple Runner.path

Tags: karate

I am using 2 Runner.path to run tests, and find that karate-reports is generated for every Runner.path.However, I need only one, and hope aggregate that 2 karate-reports to one.

I have tried to add .backupReportDir(false) to Runner builder, and yes, there is only one karate-reports outputed, but some files like karate-summary.html are overwrited, and from karate-summary.html I can only see the summary of only one Runner.

when I have multiple karate Runner in my code, I hope to get only one karate-reports, and one karate-summary.html in karate-reports dolder, moreover, all the test case result is included in karate-summary.html.